# Cannot return datatable

Tags: c#, excel, csv, checkbox, datagridview

```
public DataTable ExcelToDatatable_dt1  
{
    get  
    {  
        foreach (GridViewRow rowItem in GridView1.Rows)  
        {  
            CheckBox chk;  
            // gets the Debit Reference number for each row checked  
            string productId = GridView1.DataKeys[rowItem.RowIndex].Value.ToString();  
           chk = (CheckBox)(rowItem.Cells[0].FindControl("RowChecker"));  
           if (chk.Checked)  

           {  
               string fileName = Session["fileName"].ToString();  
               //string fileName = "Collection.csv";  
               // put the file name here  
               string strSql = "SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "] WHERE DDIREF = ["+ productId +]";  
               string strCSVConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(".\\Files\\") + ";" + "Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;'";  


               using (FileStream filestr = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(".\\Files\\") + "\\schema.ini",  
                   FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))  
               {  
                   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filestr))  
                   {  
                       writer.WriteLine("[" + fileName + "]");  
                       writer.WriteLine("ColNameHeader=False");  
                       writer.WriteLine("Format=CSVDelimited");  
                       writer.WriteLine("DateTimeFormat=dd-MMM-yy");  

                       //Message_ltr.Text += positionList[0].ToString();  

                       for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)  
                           //if (((positionList[i].ToString() != null) && (positionList[i].ToString() != "")) && ((nameList[i].ToString() != null) && (nameList[i].ToString() != "")))  
                           writer.WriteLine("Col" + positionList[i].ToString() + "=" + nameList[i].ToString() + " Text Width 100");  
                       //writer.WriteLine("Col2=SortCode Text Width 30");  

                       writer.Close();  
                       writer.Dispose();  
                   }  
                   filestr.Close();  
                   filestr.Dispose();  
               }  


               OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, strCSVConnString);  
               DataTable dtbCSV = new DataTable();  
               oleda.Fill(dtbCSV);  

               return dtbCSV;  
           }  

        }  

        return null;// instead of null I want to return dtbCSV here  
        }
```

This gives an error

> "Error 45 'DirectDebit.Interbacs.CompanyUpload.ExcelToDatatable_dt1.get': not all code paths return a value".

The error is due to the return statement which is not in the correct scope. But the problem is, I want to return dtbCSV and I am not able return  that within the "get" scope as dtCSV does not exist within the get context, I have no knowledge of passing the values between scopes within a return method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `DataTable dtbCSV = new DataTable();` before your `foreach` statement (and remove the other declaration).

**Edit**
Note: This will put `dtbCSV` in the scope of the entire `get` block instead of just in your `if` statement.

Comment: hi thnx for sorting out this issue .. really appreciate that. I am having one more problem with the query , In the above example file name is the .csv file . The sql query works fine with the "Select * from ["+ file name +" but it throws an error when I use WHERE DDRIEF= product id;

Comment: Error:No value given for one or more required parameters

Comment: You're missing a double quote after the second +: `["+ productId +]";` Change it to: `["+ productId + "]";` and see if that helps

Comment: Actually, after looking at it more, you should remove the square brackets around product ID. The square brackets will make it reference it like a column (unless that's what you want). You should really be using parameters for this. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.aspx